# External Function Call Blocks UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task

I am working on an application that talks to a motion controller over ethernet.

To connect to the controller I use a library provided by the supplier, to connect you create an instance of the controller than then tell it to connect, this has the chance to block for a few seconds (with no controllable timeout) if there is no controller present. This cause freeze ups in the UI.

To avoid this I thought I would be able to use Tasks to run the connection in a different thread.

```
ConnectionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        RMCLink rmc = RMCLink.CreateEthernetLink(DeviceType.RMC70, "192.168.0.55");
        RMC.Connect();
    }
    catch
    {
        this.logger.Log("Failed to connect");
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

This has no effect whatsoever and the UI still locks up.

I think I am using them properly as if I replace it with the below code the UI is fine even though the separate thread takes a few seconds before the message comes out.

```
ConnectionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    int x = 1;
    while (x != 0) x++;
    this.logger.Log("Failed to connect");
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Is there any way I can identify what is going on and prevent calls that I do not know anything about their inner workings from locking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async`/`await`, something along the lines of:

```
public async void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CreateEthernetLink();

    this.logger.Log("Connected!");
}

private async Task CreateEthernetLink()
{ 
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
        try
        {
            RMCLink rmc = RMCLink.CreateEthernetLink(DeviceType.RMC70, "192.168.0.55");
            rmc.Connect();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.logger.Log("Failed to connect");
        }});

     await task;
 }
```

The `await` will capture the current thread (or `SynchronizationContext` - in this case the UI thread which is being blocked) and restore it after the async work has been completed.

So the threading is all handled for you behind the scenes and you should notice no difference in your application other than the fact that your application no longer freezes when performing connections.

**EDIT:** I also noticed in your code your initializing **rmc** but calling connect on **RMC**. I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Though a fine answer, consider posting an explanation along with your code.  Thanks!

Comment: Will this actually perform the RMCLink.CreateEthernetLink call on a separate thread to the caller?

Comment: @MickyDuncan I've added some explanation. Thanks.

Comment: This code will not work because the CreateEthernetLink does not perform any await inside it. Therefore it cannot be marked as async.

Comment: It will now compile but it will run synchronously because it does not have any await inside it. Therefore it has the original problem.

Comment: This does not appear to work any differently, I had to go though some bother to get async not throwing errors (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx), and had to use Task.Factory.StartNew instead of run (.Net 4) any other ideas

Comment: I've tested this using `Thread.Sleep()` in place of the connection call and it does not block the UI. Are you able to post more of your code (as in the full method) and maybe I'll be able to spot what's wrong?

Comment: Also, if you replace the connection code with `Thread.Sleep(5000);` does it still block?

Comment: I don't think any additional code will help i replace the connect line with the while loop that consumes a few seconds, or a sleep it works perfectly (so did how I posted in my original question) hence wanting to how I could discover what the rmc.connect method is doing to block the UI thread.

Comment: If you pause execution during connection and look at Debug -> Windows -> Threads is the connection on a seperate Worker Thread or the Main Thread?

Comment: Can you post anything else about RMCLink? Why is it static for instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72190/discussion-between-hugoagogo-and-ragtimewilly).